# can't make the main tag expand over all the space in the monitor

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working in the base.html of a dashboard for my webapp, and trying to make a div  expand over all the monitor's space left after the sidebar navigation that tacks 3 columns left. also the button that it meant to be a toggler when the size of the screen is small don't contain the sidebarMenu.
the code for the this page:

```
 {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Drivers_App_Management/css/base.css' %}" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      /* Chart.js */
      @keyframes chartjs-render-animation{from{opacity:.99}to{opacity:1}}.chartjs-render-monitor{animation:chartjs-render-animation 1ms}.chartjs-size-monitor,.chartjs-size-monitor-expand,.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink{position:absolute;direction:ltr;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1}.chartjs-size-monitor-expand>div{position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0}.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink>div{position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0;top:0}
    </style>


   {% block title %}
   {% endblock title %}

  </head>
    <body>
      <header class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 me-0 px-3" href="{% url 'Drivers_App_Management:index' %}">
          <span class="d-flex">
            <img src="{% static 'Drivers_App_Management/media/ST.png' %}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="47" height="60" alt="...">
          </span>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="media-body ml-2 d-none d-lg-block">
          <span class="mb-0 text-sm  font-weight-bold">
            Bonjour:
            {{ user.first_name }}
            {{user.registration_number}}
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
          <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Link to somewhere </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-dark sidebar-dark collapse">
            <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
              <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#"> Dashboard </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Orders </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Products </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Customers </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                <span>Title</span>
              </h6>
              <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Month</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Last Quarter </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Year-end sale </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Sociale </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <main id="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div class="chartjs-size-monitor">
              <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand">
                <div class=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink">
                <div class=""></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
              <h1 class="h2"> Tableau de bord</h1>
            </div>
              {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js" integrity="sha384-uO3SXW5IuS1ZpFPKugNNWqTZRRglnUJK6UAZ/gxOX80nxEkN9NcGZTftn6RzhGWE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha384-zNy6FEbO50N+Cg5wap8IKA4M/ZnLJgzc6w2NqACZaK0u0FXfOWRRJOnQtpZun8ha" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

the **base.css** is:

```
body {
  font-size: .875rem;
}
header {
  background-color: #e21718;
}
.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* rtl:raw:
  right: 0;
  */
  bottom: 0;
  /* rtl:remove */
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
  padding: 48px 0 0; /* Height of navbar */
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .sidebar {
    top: 5rem;
  }
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #727272;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather,
.sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * Navbar
 */

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  top: .25rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.navbar .form-control {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
```

the wepage looks like :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the mistake of specifying a class listing **id** for the `main` tag. Here:

```
<main id="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
```

Since these are classes, use the **class** attribute. Like this:

```
<main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
```

The **id** attribute cannot contain a list of identifiers from the point of view of correct layout. This is attribute name must contain only **one** value.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see it.

Comment: the toggler problem still persist.

Comment: @E.Mohammed, but it works for me - https://ibb.co/FbrS3Y0